# Reading 32 bit binary numbers in java

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to read five 32-bit binary numbers. I am correctly reading 1, 5, 8, and 45, but I am not able to read 134,217,728. My code is as follows:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("C:/Sn3.edf");
BufferedInputStream buff = new BufferedInputStream(file)) {
    int in;
    for (int i=0;i<count;i++) {
        in = buff.read();
        System.out.println("       " + in);
    }
```

I tried to change int to long but did not work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the content of your file?

Comment: `BufferedInputStream#read` reads only one byte.

Comment: @Luiggi: Content are five numbers. 4 bytes (binary) for each number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you didn't post a complete code example and you didn't post the contents of your input file, but here goes anyway.

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#read%28%29)

According to the JDK docs, `BufferedInputStream.read()` returns a byte at a time.  You're reading a byte at a time, storing it in `in`, and printing it to console.  That code will only work for you if each of your numbers is 8 bits in size.  Since you have 32-bit integers stored in a file, you'll need to read 4 bytes at a time (32 bits / 8 bits/byte) and then do some math to turn those bytes into a Java `int`.

Comment: Or use `Scanner` instead of `BufferedInputStream` to read the file content `int` by `int` or line by line.

Comment: @orzechowskid: thank you. Any recommendations on how to read 4 bytes at a time?

Comment: @munir Read one byte four times, or use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).